# jQuery / coffeescript : Hide all but the selected input div

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have an input checkbox, defined in the last line of html below. I am using jQuery / Coffeescript to try to hide all the other divs on the page with the class "control-group ..." when the input box is checked. The problem is, I want to keep this particular div, but have not been able to. Instead they all disappear. I have used the "not()" method and many jQuery selectors in different ways in the code without success. Can you help?  Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="control-group boolean optional question_answers_correct_answer">
  <label class="boolean optional control-label" for="question_answers_attributes_0_correct_answer">Correct answer</label>
    <div  class="controls"><input name="question[answers_attributes][0][correct_answer]" value="0" type="hidden">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input class="boolean optional" id="question_answers_attributes_0_correct_answer" name="question[answers_attributes][0][correct_answer]" value="1" type="checkbox">
```

Coffeescript

```
jQuery ->
  $('input[name*="correct_answer"]').on "change", (event) ->
    $("div.control-group.boolean.optional.question_answers_correct_answer").hide(300)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$("div.control-group").hide(300)
$(".boolean.optional.question_answers_correct_answer").show()
```

or:

```
$("div.control-group").not(".boolean.optional.question_answers_correct_answer").hide(300)
```

Answer (score 0):

if($("div.control-group").hasClass('.boolean.optional.question_answers_correct_answer'))
    $("div.control-group").show()
else
    $("div.control-group").hide(300);